# How to get correct API endpoint for 3 levels nested files

Tags: api, google-api, google-drive-api

[image]

I would like to get some files id from current folder. I am sending request in postman and I am using google drive v3.

I can pass authentification and my url endpoint look like
GET

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='1Bda8VqVvkuuTqeSPw48NSl4kXijCboi6' in parents
```

it get all files for current folder but it is in my drive I would like to get files from shared drive.

I can get that drive with endpoint

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives
```

but than I don't know how to continue

Comment: If you want to retrieve the files under the folder of `concept`, have you already known the folder ID of `concept`? Or, do you want to retrieve all files in your shared Drive?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this way. What you're missing is de [corpora](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list#parameters) parameter

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?corpora=drive&includeItemsFromAllDrives=true&includeTeamDriveItems=true&supportsAllDrives=true&supportsTeamDrives=true&teamDriveId=1Bda8VqVvkuuTqeSPw48NSl4kXijCboi6&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

That parameters works to group files to which the query applies